# How to identify cause of frequent router reboots

Tags: wireless-networking, router, reboot

What tools can I use to identify the rebooting cause(s) of my router. I am not able to reproduce the reboots. The frequency is more than 4 times per day.

Background:
My LTE router (Huawei) used to reboot here and there, that's why I was sending it back to service (two times). With the loaner devices (ZTE), I had no issues at all. Having the mainboard replaced and getting a new device, the reboot issue still persists. As this is a bit weird, I tried my Sony Z1 Compact today as a router (WiFi hotspot) and, believe it or not, I also had connection drops (cave: The WiFi drops, not the mobile connection which I would expect if the signal is bad). I currently have 7 devices connected (Chromecasts, Receiver, Android Smartphones) that are permantently connected.

Comment: I don't see the point in investing your personal time in debugging a buggy closed-source product. The manufacturer is unlikely to fix it in a timely manner. Sadly the only real solution in your power is to buy better equipment.

Comment: Fully understand your argument, but since I got the same issue with the Android hotspot, I got curious if it is really a device in my home network causing this - and why.

Comment: Bigger question is how do you know it is "rebooting?" You mentioned signal dropping, but that is not synonymous with rebooting.

Comment: Hi @Appleoddity, the Huawei E5186 has few status LEDs. The WiFi and LTE signal LED go off, the status LED goes red. The sequence and duration is the same for a reboot. With the "signal bad" I was referring to the Android hotspot: Android did not reboot, the hotspot icon did not disappear but there was no WiFi anymore. Also here, it took a while until WiFi recovered. I expect both the router and the Android hotspot to have permanent WiFi (independent of LTE signal strength).

Answer (score 1):

The Huawei E5186 has reboot/reset issues when 2.4GHz is enabled.  Try disabling 2.4GHz and operating on only 5GHz (if your devices allow you to only make use of 5GHz) and your reboots/resets will stop.  This is an issue with the router and I don't think that there is a fix out for this problem.

Link [here](https://yescrowd.optus.com.au/t5/Wi-Fi-Talk-Home-Zone/Huawei-e5186-modem-reset-when-2-4G-wifi-turn-on/td-p/196199)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Do you have a reference for that? However, this does not explain the same behavior as with the Android hotspot. Unfortunately, I am not able to disable 2.4 GHz (as nearly all devices do not provide 5 GHz radio), but I'll try disabling 5 GHz and IPv6 DHCP, which I read in other forums (for another device).

Comment: @Daniel - Added to original answer. Enjoy!